# Let $G$ be a finite $3$-group. Is it possible for character table of $G$ to have the entry $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i$?

Tags: representation-theory

In my view, the answer is no. My attempt is as follows:

Let $G$ be a group of order $3^k$. Suppose $\phi$ is an irreducible representation of $G$ of degree $n$ such that $\chi_\phi(g)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i$ for some $g \in G$.

If $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $\phi_g$, then we have $\lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i$.

Since $\phi_g^{|G|}=\text{Id}$, we have $\lambda_i^{|G|}=\lambda_i^{3^k}=1$ for all $i$.

I want to show that this is not possible, but I am having trouble getting a rigorous argument. Some more information that I have is that the degree of $\phi$ divides $|G|$, i.e., $n$ divides $3^k$.

Comment: *Hint*: What do you know about the degrees of the field extensions $\mathbb{Q}[\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n]/\mathbb{Q}[\chi_\phi(g)]/\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: When you write $\lambda_i^{3k}$, do you mean $\lambda_i^{3^k}$?

Comment: Every eigenvalue of a matrix representation is a $3^n$th root of unity, which have Galois degree $2\cdot 3^{n-1}.$  So you can’t express a primitive $8$th root of unity as a sum of $3^n$th roots of unity, by Galois theory.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. I corrected it.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks. I got it. If $\lambda$ is a primitive $3^k$-th root of unity, then $\mathbb{Q}[\lambda] \supseteq \mathbb{Q}[\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n] \supseteq \mathbb{Q}[\chi_{\phi}(g)] \supseteq \mathbb{Q}$. But $[\mathbb{Q}[\lambda]:\mathbb{Q}]=2 \cdot 3^{k-1}$ and $[\mathbb{Q}[\chi_{\phi}(g)]:\mathbb{Q}]=4$. Which is a contradiction.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Not every $3^n$-th root of unity will have degree of Galois extension $2\cdot 3^{n-1}$, but only the primitive ones.

Comment: Thought I wrote primitive, but I guess I did not. But it will still be a primitive root $3^m$th root for some $m,$ which is enough to get the Galois result. @RamandeepSinghArora